# Raid 0 Performance Decreased

Tags: hard-drive, windows-10, performance, raid, storage-spaces

I was trying to understand the performance benefits of RAID. I created 4 virtual disks in Windows 10 (10 GB each). I then set up 2 of them as Stripped volumes and the other 2 as spanned volumes. Now I have two disk (20 GB Each) one stripped and the other spanned. As per my assumption the stripped disk should have 2x better performance compared to the spanned one, but when I do a Disk Speed test (using Atto Benchmark) I am getting around 100 MB/s on spanned but only 50 MB/s on stripped which is contradictory.

Am I missing something or is my RAID 0 array wrong.

Comment: When you say "Virtual Disks", do you mean files acting as disks?  If thats the case, then your test is flawed as you are still using 1 physical disk for a start, so the position of the head on the disk does not magically change to behave like 2 disks.    Also, on a spinning disk, the outside tracks perform about twice as fast as the inside ones, so the positions on the physical disk can make a difference  (google Short Stroking)

Comment: I am rather surprised it works as well as it does. In real RAID all 4 drives would be accessed simultaneously, which is what provides the performance gain. But in a virtual environment the disks are represented by 4 separate files which must be accessed sequentially, likely with significant head seeks between each one. Fortunately the file system helps out here. Operations aren't done in the order requested but are arranged to minimize head seeks. Buffering also helps.

Answer (score 2):

Your understanding is correct on a theoretical level for real raid, but keep in mind that this is not "real" hardware raid. You are using virtual disks and the raid is not implemented by a hardware controller, but by the OS itself. This means that in your case the raid overhead is being absorbed by the OS and operations which are more complicated are longer to do. On top of which, you are probably writing to the same physical disk altogether, so the speed may not be what you are expecting out of a real RAID implementation depending on fragmentation and area of writing on the disk.

Lastly the RAID 1 (spanned) implementation is probably not 100% real time in the sense that you are probably writing to one disk and a "worker process" is probably doing the copy over to the second disk (This is just a hunch though and I cannot find any information on this for the Windows implementation as of writing this). So in which case your RAID 0 (striped) data has to be written to different virtual disks, as each disk only has half the information, but your RAID 1 implementation only has to write to one disk, which gets copied by another process.